# Tests assertHTTP 400

Tags: python, django, django-testing

When I try to save a model that has expired my custom error returns a 400 BadRequest. For example:

**Model:**

```
  def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):

         if self.incentive.has_expired():
                    raise CustomBadRequest(
                        code="missing_key",
                        message="Expired on {expiry_date}"
                        .format(expiry_date=self.incentive.expiry_date))
```

I now want to write a test to test this. Is there an assertHTTP 400 test or something: This is what I have so far.....

```
def test_expiry(self):
    """
    Check that saving fails when expiry date is passed
    """
    yesterday = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=1)
    self.incentive.expiry_date = yesterday
    self.incentive.save()
    Recipient.objects.create(incentive=self.incentive,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's unittest has assertRaises() method that catches exception.

[see python doc about assertRaises()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html?highlight=assertraises#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)